# Using Matplotlib with Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, matplotlib, concurrency

I have built a simple web application using Django that reads a csv file and allows users to plot graphs by selecting X & Y attributes.

The frontend makes use of AJAX calls to call backend methods to plot graphs using Python's Matplotlib. The issue arises when the plots are called asynchronously, causing a race condition: Different charts get plotted to the same figure.

In attempts to overcome this problem, I assign random "id" to each user so that I can call matplotlib to get a figure number -- So each user plots on different figures.

```
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
matplotlib.use('agg')

#cm is an array containing 2 confusion matrices generated from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html
def plot_confusion_matrix(user_id, cm, classes, path,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion Matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    id = user_id + random.randint(1, 10000)
    fig = plt.figure(id)
    axis1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
    title1 = title + " (train)"
    title2 =title + " (test)"
    def plot_cm(cm, title):
        plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
        plt.title(title)
        #plt.colorbar()
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)
        thresh = cm.max() / 2.
        for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
            plt.text(j, i, cm[i, j],
                     horizontalalignment="center",
                     color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.ylabel('True label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plot_cm(cm=cm[0], title=title1)
    axis2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
    plot_cm(cm=cm[1], title=title2)
    plt.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig(path)
    plt.close(id)
```

However, this does not solve the problem -- When a user plots 3 graphs at one time the graphs overlap on each other.

Comment: show us the rest how you plot into figures, do you use axes?

Comment: @RadekHofman Have added the full code for plotting. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, try to plot directly into the axis you create like this:

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(user_id, cm, classes, path,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion Matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    id = user_id + random.randint(1, 10000)
    fig = plt.figure(id)
    axis1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
    title1 = title + " (train)"
    title2 =title + " (test)"
    def plot_cm(cm, title, ax):
        ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
        ax.set_title(title)
        #plt.colorbar()
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
        ax.set_xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
        ax.set_yticks(tick_marks, classes)
        thresh = cm.max() / 2.
        for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
            ax.text(j, i, cm[i, j],
                     horizontalalignment="center",
                     color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

        plt.tight_layout()
        ax.set_ylabel('True label')
        ax.set_xlabel('Predicted label')
    plot_cm(cm=cm[0], title=title1, axis1)
    axis2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
    plot_cm(cm=cm[1], title=title2, axis2)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(path)
    plt.close(id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but using the code it appears there are errors when I try to call methods on the axis itself. Other than imshow(), all other methods cannot be used on the axes object.

Comment: yes, I tried to change it so ti works, like `xticks` -> `set_xticks`. Even with this `set_` it does not work?

Comment: ax.set_xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45) returns "unexpected arg rotation"; and after removing the 'rotation' I get the error "max() arg is an empty sequence"

Comment: ok, `rotation` is and argument of `ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels,.. rotation=45` not `set_xticks()` but with the empty sequence I cannot help, seems it comes empty from the outside. Did you check what is there? Or was it working before? Don't you import everything from `plt` so there is a confusion between your `cm` and `plt.cm` ?

Comment: For the ax.set_xticklabels(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45), I am trying to assign classes (an array of string) to tick_marks (an array of int) which specifies the positions for the labels (classes). However using the ax it only takes in 'labels' -- is there a workaround for this?

Comment: firstly you set the ticks - locations - by `ax.set_xticks()` and then you assign labels to these ticks `ax.set_xticklabels()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! By the way, the cm.max() issue arises when multiple plots are happening together -- the plt.figure(id) is being called by different threads and the axes are added wrongly to different plots. I fixed this by adding the subplots first, and passing in the axes later.

Comment: Hi, Ivan. Did you solve the problem?  I face the same situation as you, return a static image to html. But I think each time ajax post a request matplotlib need to create a new figure. Is there any efficient way to achieve this goal?

Comment: @LiZiming Hi, I solved the problem by creating a new figure with a different id each time. To avoid collision of id, you can use the thread id for whichever process is running it - otherwise, a sufficiently large N should work as well. Hope that helps!